# What is the "chariot of salvation"?

Tags: habakkuk

Habakkuk 3:8

> Was your wrath against the rivers, O LORD? Was your anger against the
> rivers, or your indignation against the sea, when you rode on your
> horses, on your chariot of salvation?

What is the chariot of salvation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beautiful poetry of Hab 3 prayer (or song?) of praise is unsurprisingly filled with metaphors and allusions to Israel's history, especially the escape from Egypt.

- The reference in Hab 3:5, 6 appears to allude to the plagues of Egypt.
- Hab 3:7 is another indirect allusion to Egypt
- Hab 3:8 appears to refer to the crossing of the Red Sea and the Jordan
- Hab 3:9 might allude to the conquest of Canaan

Specifically concerning the "chariot of salvation", Ellicott comments as follows:

> Of salvation.—Better, for salvation, or for deliverance. The allusion
> is obviously to Israel’s miraculous passage through the Red Sea and
> the Jordan. The “horses” and “chariots” which are here the symbols of
> Divine might, come in the more fittingly in view of Exodus 14 (see
> Habakkuk 3:14 seq.), where Pharaoh, pursued with “horses and
> chariots,” only to find Jehovah Himself arrayed against him.

The Cambridge commentary is also helpful:

> chariots of salvation] Or, of victory, deliverance; lit. thy chariots
> which are victory, i.e. victorious, used to victory. The “horses” and
> “chariots” here are the storm-clouds on which Jehovah rides. Psalm
> 18:10; Isaiah 19:1; Deuteronomy 33:26; Psalm 68:33.
>
> 8–11. Is Jehovah’s anger against the rivers and the sea?
>
> The reference to the “sea,” which is naturally to be understood as the
> Red Sea, is in favour of taking the whole passage as a description of
> the redemption of the Exodus. Jehovah moves in a glorious
> manifestation of light from His ancient seats in Paran and Sinai; He
> directs His movement towards the Red Sea for the delivery of His
> people. Sea and land are thrown into wild commotion and terror at His
> appearing. This suggests the prophet’s question, Is thine anger
> against the sea?

Answer (score 1):

What are Your **Chariot(s)** of salvation?

מַרְכְּבֹתֶ֖**יךָ** **Markevot**eikha | "[Your]-Chariots" (plural).

- If Habbakuk 3:8 had stated "Your-Chariot" (singular), then the text would have said : מִרְכֶּבֶת**יךָ** **Mirkev[e]t**eikha .

---

**Chavaquq חֲבַקּ֖וּק | "Habbakuk" 3:8**

> Was YHVH angry with the rivers? Is His wrath against the rivers, or His fury against the sea? Only that You rode on Your steeds with **Your-Chariots** of salvation." ( הֲבִנְהָרִים֙ חָרָ֣ה יְהֹוָ֔ה אִם־בַּנְּהָרִים֙ אַפֶּ֔ךָ אִם־בַּיָּ֖ם עֶבְרָתֶ֑ךָ כִּ֚י תִרְכַּב֙ עַל־סוּסֶ֔יךָ מַרְכְּבֹתֶ֖יךָ יְשׁוּעָֽה )

Your-Chariots | מַרְכְּבֹתֶ֖**יךָ** **Markevot**eikha refers to Clouds.

- See also Deuteronomy 33:26